# Displaying images from a matrix field from a related field

Tags: matrix, relations

I have a section that is a single type. On this page there is a relation ship ('entries') field where the user can select a related photo gallery. Photo gallery is its own section with a matrix field on it that contains image files and image names. How when I am displaying the single page pull in the matrix field to display an image gallery. This is what I have tried but not with much luck.

I have tried

```
  {% if entry.associatedGallery is not null %}
    {% set theGallery = craft.entries.section('bb').relatedTo(entry.associatedGallery) %}
      <div class="galleria associated-gallery">
        {% for matrixBlock in theGallery.albumImages %}
          {% set asset = matrixBlock.imageFile.first() %}
            {% if asset %}
              <a href="{{ asset.getUrl() }}"><img src="{{ asset.getUrl('homeThumb') }}" data-title="{{ matrixBlock.imageName }}"></a>
            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
      </div>
    {% else %}
      <h1> Apparently its null</h1>  
  {% endif %}
```

and

```
  {% if entry.associatedGallery is not null %}
    {% set theGallery = entry.associatedGallery %}
      <div class="galleria associated-gallery">
        {% for matrixBlock in theGallery.albumImages %}
          {% set asset = matrixBlock.imageFile.first() %}
            {% if asset %}
              <a href="{{ asset.getUrl() }}"><img src="{{ asset.getUrl('homeThumb') }}" data-title="{{ matrixBlock.imageName }}"></a>
            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
      </div>
    {% else %}
      <h1> Apparently its null</h1>  
  {% endif %}
```

I think I am missing something fundamental about how relationships are defined.

Comment: Are you pulling just the first image of the related gallery? Or do you want to show all the images of the related gallery?

Comment: Looking to pull all images in a gallery. The middle part of that code from 'for matrixBlock in.... is pretty much the same as I use on a gallery entry page. It just uses .first() because each block only contains one image and one title.

Answer (score 1):

Relationship field is defined like:

```
{% for relatedItem in entry.relatedItemField %}
  {{ relatedItem.someField }} {{ relatedItem.someOtherField }}    
{% endfor %}
```

So maybe:

```
{% if entry.associatedGallery | length %}
    {% for theGallery in entry.associatedGallery %}
        {% for matrixBlock in theGallery.albumImages %}
            {% if matrixBlock.imageFile | length %}
                {% for asset in matrixBlock.imageFile.first() %}
                    <a href="{{ asset.getUrl() }}"><img src="{{ asset.getUrl('homeThumb') }}" data-title="{{ matrixBlock.imageName }}"></a>
                {% endfor %}
            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: That seems to output a whole lot of info as the asset things like id, publish date and a whole bunch else that doesn't make sense to me but it did get me thinking and rereading the documentation on entry fields specifically. I think it was the .first() I was missing since I have it only set to be one related entry. I think your example might be missing a step where each related entry is defined. Not sure I will have to try a multiple relations example later.

Answer (score 1):

After using the above and re-reading the docs I got this to work.

```
  {% set relatedGallery = entry.associatedGallery.first() %}
  {% if relatedGallery %}
    {% for matrixBlock in relatedGallery.albumImages %}
      {% set asset = matrixBlock.imageFile.first() %}
        {% if asset %}
          <a href="{{ asset.getUrl() }}"><img src="{{ asset.getUrl('homeThumb') }}" data-title="{{ matrixBlock.imageName }}"></a>
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}    
  {% endif %}
```